# Zookeeper java class for autopurge not found

Tags: apache-zookeeper, clickhouse

I have this zookeeper config:

```
autopurge.snapRetainCount=10
autopurge.purgeInterval=1
snapCount=3000000
```

And my `/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/data` dir goes large, no `autopurge` happens.

I try clean up this mess with `zkCleanup.sh` but it does nothing.

```
sysadmin@clickhouse-node1:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin$ ls /opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/data/version-2/ | wc -l
18
sysadmin@clickhouse-node1:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin$ ./zkCleanup.sh -n 10  
sysadmin@clickhouse-node1:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin$ ls /opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/data/version-2/ | wc -l
18

sysadmin@clickhouse-node1:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11$ ls data/version-2/
log.9028ed00e  log.902eafb66  log.903362dcb  log.90374bde5  log.903b5f685  log.903f8e16a  log.b000000a8  log.b004d4eac  log.b0083c3e1
log.902b9c065  log.9030ece30  log.903590e4a  log.90395a935  log.903d9b0f0  log.90421e5d6  log.b002462e2  log.b0068bba3  log.b00a38f08
```

My zkCleanup.sh https://pastebin.com/Q9XSpSfz

UPD: log from new zoo cleanup script:

`sysadmin@clickhouse-node1:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin$ ./zoo_clean.sh -n 10
/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/data
/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/logs
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Dzookeeper.log.dir=. -Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE -cp /opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../build/classes:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../lib/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.11.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/../conf: org.apache.zookeeper.server.PurgeTxnLog /opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/logs /opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/data -n 10`

Nothing happen again

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: try `jar -tvf zookeeper.jar  |grep PurgeTxnLog`. and what's the relationship between `/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/data` and `/opt/zoo/data`.

Comment: why not use `zkCleanup.sh` instead of fill `java` command yourself.  seems that you didn't include your `slf4japi` and `slf4j-log4j12` in your classpath.

Comment: zkCleanup.sh dosnt work, i dont understand bash. Maybe any problem in it. But script execute without problems.

Comment: try `./bin/zkCleanup.sh -n 10`

Comment: can you update that in the question body ? and list the files under `/opt/zookeeper-3.4.11/data/version-2/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in zkCleanup.sh in 3.4.11 docker image https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/pull/475

Simple fix is to edit zkCleanup.sh from

org.apache.zookeeper.server.PurgeTxnLog "$ZOODATALOGDIR" "$ZOODATADIR" $*

to

org.apache.zookeeper.server.PurgeTxnLog "$ZOODATADIR" "$ZOODATALOGDIR" $*

Answer (score 1):

**`dataDir` and `dataLogDir` in your `conf/zoo.cfg` are relative paths**, the following instructions may help :

```
cd /opt/zookeeper-3.4.11
./bin/zkCleanup.sh -n 10
```

then you can see the output like:

```
Removing file: Mar 15, 2018 1:57:16 PM  data/log/version-2/log.9028ed00e
Removing file: Mar 12, 2018 5:33:11 PM  data/log/version-2/log.902eafb66
```

Comment: make this, nothing happen, maybe problem in shell script zkCleanup.sh. Add it to topic.

Answer (score 0):

https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/tips/#zookeeper
Clickhouse required zookeper 3.5+

Comment: Zookeeper 3.4.11 supported options autopurge.snapRetainCount and
autopurge.purgeInterval